# Is knapSack 0-1 problem where weights equal to costs is also NP hard?

Tags: np-complete

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem):

> Given a set of items, each with a weight and a value, determine the
> number of each item to include in a collection so that the total
> weight is less than or equal to a given limit and the total value is
> as large as possible

Given that all items costs are 1$ for 1Kg, aka weights are equal to values. Will this problem will also be NP-hard like knapSack 0-1?

Comment: Consider the subset sum problem.

Comment: @BrianBorchers the answer to the subset sum problem is boolean, how can you turn it into finding the smallest value above 0?

Comment: The subset sum is also NP complete, not NP hard. Can you find a way to make an NP hard variation on the subset sum problem that is entirely equivalent to your problem? Or maybe change your problem into a decision problem which can then be seen as a rewrite of the subset sum problem?